# The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time;

Tags: swift, swiftui

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable
> time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

I know, what is means, but I dont know, how to do this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MeetingTimerView: View {
    let speakers: [ScrumTimer.Speaker]
    let theme: Theme
    
    private var currentSpeaker: String {
        speakers.first(where: { !$0.isCompleted })?.name ?? "Someone"
    }

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .strokeBorder(Color.blue, lineWidth: 14)
            .overlay {
                VStack {
                    Text(currentSpeaker)
                        .font(.title)
                    Text("в етері")
                }
                .accessibilityElement(children: .combine)
                .foregroundStyle(theme.accentColor)
            }
            .overlay {
                ForEach(speakers) { speaker in
                    if speaker.isCompleted, let index = speakers.firstIndex(where: { !0.id == speaker.id }) {
                        SpeakerArc(speakerIndex: index, totalSpeakers: speakers.count)
                            .rotation(Angle(degrees: -90))
                            .stroke(theme.mainColor, lineWidth: 10)
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}

struct MeetingTimerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var speakers: [ScrumTimer.Speaker] {
        [ScrumTimer.Speaker(name: "Bill", isCompleted: true), ScrumTimer.Speaker(name: "Cathy", isCompleted: false)]
    }
    
    static var previews: some View {
        MeetingTimerView(speakers: speakers, theme: .yellow)
    }
}
```

I try find solution in Documentation, but I dont find it

Comment: Try to remove different parts of the view one by one to see if you can identify what causes the error. `!0.id == speaker.id `, this code must be wrong. What is that exclamation mark doing there?

Comment: You do not give a default view (EmptyView() for example) if no speaker is completed. In this case SwiftUI does not know what is the content of the overlay.

Comment: Shouldn't be $0.id == speaker.id